# How to manually decrypt a file encrypted via git crypt

Tags: git, encryption, continuous-integration

I'm using a CI build that downloads a zip archive from github. At build time, I need to decrypt a file that has been encrypted with git-crypt using gpg. However, the CI build cannot decrypt the files because it is not a cloned directory tree and thus I cannot run 'git crypt unlock'.

I see the .git-crypt tree, but what are the manual steps to gpg to decrypt a file?

Comment: Have you added the CI build machine/user gpg pub key into the key chain ?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have the GPG key that the directory was encrypted with, just do the following:

```
cd encrypted-directory
git init
git-crypt unlock gpg.key
```

Comment: git-crypt minimally requires an initialized repo (git init).

Comment: Clever approach! You probably want to remember to clean up the new .git directory once you've reclaimed your data.

Comment: Actually removing the .git dependency from a locked git-crypted repo is unadvised in the first place. The OP likely forgot to unlock the repo first, and is very lucky this solution worked. A tribute to the git-crypt designer.

Comment: I had a similar problem and ended up writing a small article on the full set-up https://thearjunmdas.github.io/entries/encrypt-decrypt-files-with-git.